# Broadcom BCM43142 - Driver support on Kali Linux?

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, network-interface

I am attempting to configure a new netbook with Kali Linux.  Everything seems to be fine, except wifi isn't working.  Apparently the computer has a Broadcom BCM43142 wireless card, which doesn't have built in drivers.  Where should I look to find them, and what are my possible workarounds? Should I attempt to use an older Broadcom driver?

From `lspci -knn` <sup>Manually copied, typos are possible</sup>

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
DeviceName: Broadcom WLAN Broadcom Nami 43142 bgn 1x1 + BT 4 LE PCIe+USB NGFF 1630
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
```

---

More searching has led me to find a couple of deb packages, which I'm listing below, still figuring out which is the right one for my version of Kali.

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl
- https://wiki.debian.org/wl

My Kali version is

> Linux kali 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5kali4 (2016-01-13)
>   x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @GAD3R As you requested.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of searching, I found the `broadcom-sta-dkms` package, which explicitly supports my device, as mentioned in the README.txt.  I also had to install the appropriate linux headers for my device.  Initially I ran into several problems, particularly a message about "no headers for current kernal version" but after doing a full `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, and `apt-get dist-upgrade` I was able to `apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms`, which built a new initrm and successfully got my wireless working.